# Pass variable from Javascript to Zend framework Controller

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a Zend framework Controller as below.

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

class myDataController extends AbstractActionController
       {
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return array();
    }

    public function viewHandlerAction()
    {
        echo $_REQUEST['value'];
        $json = new JsonModel(array("abc"=>"1"));
        return $json;
    }
}
```

I am making a HTTP post request to this "viewHandlerAction" method with some data as below.

```
$http({
        method : "POST",
        url : "myData/my-data/viewHandler",
        data : JSON.stringify(formData)
    }).
    then(function(response) {
        //console.log(response);

    }, function(response) {
        //console.log(response);
    });
```

I can send this request and receive the data from the controller without any problem.But I can not access the data(formData) I sent from the client side.

Where have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.
In the action method we can get the parameter list with following.

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
```

Comment: Zend Framework also provides a `params()` controller plugin to help with this. If you do not want to have to get the request first you can use `$this->params()->fromPost();` Documentation is found at https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html